# Unable to read nodeValue using XPath when namespace is present

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<BO xmlns="http://hg.com/bo" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://hg.com/bo http://hg.com/bo.xsd">
<b>Harsh</b>
</BO>
```

I am trying to read **Harsh** present inside tag  using XPath.

When the namespace is not present, I can use this javascript line

```
var path = "/BO/b";
var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

What change should I make in the path so that I am able to fetch the node b?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use XPath expressions on XML content defined in a (default) namespace, you need to specify a namespace prefix mapping. You need some way to specify in your XPath expression that you are looking for all 'b' elements in the 'http://hg.com/bo' namespace.

In your case you could use the 'ex' prefix and map this prefix to the 'http://hg.com/bo' namespace URI. This would result in the following XPath expression that should return all 'b' elements that are declared in the 'http://hg.com/bo' namespace: '//ex:/BO/b'.